Create Outlook email while keeping progress bar on Excel sheet visible
I wrote code that completes a lot of tasks with a lot of data.
I created a progress bar visible on cells K1:K2 when the user runs the macro.
At the end of this macro, several emails are created and each of them are displayed on the screen.
The problem is the progress bar is not visible anymore.
Is there a way to minimize emails once they're created?
I tried removing the .display. I guess the emails are created but can't find them, even in drafts.
The creating email code
Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMail As Object

prenom = cel.Offset(0, 2)

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

objMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "test@test.com"
objMail.display
objMail.Attachments.Add pth & cel & " " & Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy") & ".xls"
objMail.To = prenom & "@test.com"
objMail.Subject = "extract"
objMail.HTMLBody = intro & objMail.HTMLBody
objMail.Recipients.ResolveAll
'objMail.send

objMail.Recipients.ResolveAll

Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing

I wrote objMail.save instead of objMail.display.
The emails are saved as draft, but they still pop-up over the Excel sheet.


objMail.Save will put them in the draft.

Outlook doesn't allow sending mail without the user seeing it and consenting. It's an anti-malware feature that prevents a virus from using Outlook in the background to steal your contact list and send files from your computer to a third party without your permission.

@KenWhite: Is that a feature of New outlook? Because in the classic outlook you can send email without displaying. And hence .Save will also work without displaying the email when the user does not use .display

Thanks for your answer
I've tried .save instead of .display
The emails are correcly saved as draft, but they still pop-up over the excel sheet

Did you remove the line objMail.display. I just tested it and it works.

Yes, and wrote objMail.save instead

Like I said, I just tested it and it works. See THIS. This sends the email without displaying it.  And see THIS. This saves to the drafts folder without displaing it. BTW is yours New Outlook or Classic Outlook?

I use the classic outlook
I just tried without .save and without .display (only .send) and it works like yours
The only problem is that the user wants to check the email before they are sent

So you want to display it and minimize it?

That would be perfect
I'm looking for something like .Minimize
The goal is to let the active excel window visible by the user, so that he can have a look at the progressbar from 0% to 100%

I think that can be achieved with little coding. I am stepping out for couple of hours but I will come back with a solution if no one else beats me to it :D

BTW if it is just couple of emails then it is not a problem but if there too many emails then displaying all of them will clutter your taskbar and hog windows memory. The best way would be to save it to the drafts folder and then ask the person to check it in drafts later. Thats what I have been doing for my clients.

Sure, the solution to save in drafts without pop-up on the screen would be the perfect one

I didn't see your 2nd GIF showing the .Save (https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/838bm4yj3ychp6sdth7a2/Outlook-Save.gif?rlkey=fnkywfbvrt92muvn1hrlo9rbm&e=1&dl=0)
This doesn't work for me, the email still pop-up on the screen.
There's few differences between your code and mine : I'm using HTML to write the body. After i call the .save function, i have one more task to be done in an excel sheet, and then i start again to create a new email with a loop

I used your exact code. I just changed the values of attachment and "intro" And it saved to the draft without displaying. See This

This question is similar to: VBA API declarations. Bring window to front , regardless of application. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Replace .Display with .Save to have then created in Draft.
Whether or not you do a .Send is up to you, but they do ofc disappear from Draft once they are sent.
